# WooCommerce checkout endless loading with empty AJAX response

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding a WooCommerce based shop to my page and I've run into issue with endless loading in checkout. Having read some, things I've already done were: disabling caching (normally using W3TC), disabling plugins that were flagged by WooCommerce status as "not tested with current version". To try locating issues I enabled `WP_DEBUG` and set

```php
if ( defined( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST' ) || defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) || ( defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) && WP_INSTALLING ) || wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        @ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    }
```

in `wp_debug_mode()` of `wp-includes/load.php`. This did not help at all, since the response for `?wc-ajax=update_order_review` is empty either way (but with status 200), and there is nothing related in debug.log. How should I look for what causes the response to be empty?

Comment: you're probably killing off script execution somewhere in your code with a `die` or an `exit`

Comment: How would I check for that? I have some experience mostly in C, but none with WordPress code